# Acer Swift 3 Fingerprint Scanner driver

Tags: drivers, acer, fingerprint-reader

I have an Acer Swift 3, ryzen 5, model no.- SF315-41. I haven't found the fingerprint scanner driver for Ubuntu. So, I tried the Windows version with wine but it failed. The fingerprint reader is Can anyone please help?

Here are the Infos about the fingerprint scanner:

```
Bus 003 Device 005: ID 1c7a:0570 LighTuning Technology Inc.
Device Descriptor:
bLength 18
bDescriptorType 1
bcdUSB 1.10
bDeviceClass 0 (Defined at Interface level)
bDeviceSubClass 0
bDeviceProtocol 0
bMaxPacketSize0 8
idVendor 0x1c7a LighTuning Technology Inc.
idProduct 0x0570
bcdDevice 10.41
iManufacturer 1 EgisTec
iProduct 2 EgisTec Touch Fingerprint Sensor
iSerial 3 07061E6E
bNumConfigurations 1
Configuration Descriptor:
bLength 9
bDescriptorType 2
wTotalLength 32
bNumInterfaces 1
bConfigurationValue 1
iConfiguration 0
bmAttributes 0xa0
(Bus Powered)
Remote Wakeup
MaxPower 100mA
Interface Descriptor:
bLength 9
bDescriptorType 4
bInterfaceNumber 0
bAlternateSetting 0
bNumEndpoints 2
bInterfaceClass 255 Vendor Specific Class
bInterfaceSubClass 0
bInterfaceProtocol 0
iInterface 0
Endpoint Descriptor:
bLength 7
bDescriptorType 5
bEndpointAddress 0x83 EP 3 IN
bmAttributes 2
Transfer Type Bulk
Synch Type None
Usage Type Data
wMaxPacketSize 0x0040 1x 64 bytes
bInterval 0
Endpoint Descriptor:
bLength 7
bDescriptorType 5
bEndpointAddress 0x04 EP 4 OUT
bmAttributes 2
Transfer Type Bulk
Synch Type None
Usage Type Data
wMaxPacketSize 0x0040 1x 64 bytes
bInterval 3
Device Status: 0x0002
(Bus Powered)
Remote Wakeup Enabled
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if it like works, but i've found a semi-completed driver repo. https://github.com/indev29/egis0570
Just give it a try.